# POST não recebe os dados

Tags: php, post, controller, view

Estou com um problema na hora de recuperar os dados do formulário.

Eu tenho esse trecho na minha pagina, ele recebe o `array` contato e eu imprimo os dados nos respectivos campos, eu clico no link no fim pra enviar os novos dados para o controller(isso e para alteração de um contato já cadastrado). Ate ai tudo bem, ele segue pro meu método corretamente mas na hora da recuperação dos dados via POST vem tudo vazio.

Esse trecho e a minha pagina.

```html
<form action='alterando_contato' method="post"> 
    <h4>Alterar contato</h4>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nome">Nome completo</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-md" name="newnome" value="<?php echo $contato['nome']; ?>"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">E-mail</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-md" name="newemail" value="<?php echo $contato['email']; ?>"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="telefone">Telefone</label>
        <input type="tel" class="form-control form-control-md" name="newcelular" value="<?php echo $contato['celular']; ?>"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nome">Redes sociais</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-md" name="newfacebook" value="<?php echo $contato['facebook']; ?>"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-md" name="newlinkedin" value="<?php echo $contato['linkedin']; ?>"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-md" name="newtwitter" value="<?php echo $contato['twitter']; ?>"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-md" name="newinstagram" value="<?php echo $contato['instagram']; ?>"/>
    </div>

    <a href="<?php echo base_url('alterando_contato').'/'.$contato; ?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Alterar</a>

</form>
```

Minha controller.

```php
public function alterarContato($id){
    $this->load->model('Contato');
    $newnome = trim($this->input->post('newnome', true));
    $newemail = trim($this->input->post('newemail', true));
    $newcelular = trim($this->input->post('newcelular', true));
    $newfacebook = trim($this->input->post('newfacebook', true));
    $newlinkedin = trim($this->input->post('newlinkedin', true));
    $newtwitter = trim($this->input->post('newtwitter', true));
    $newinstagram = trim($this->input->post('newinstagram', true));
        $dados = array(
            'nome' => $newnome,
            'email' => $newemail,
            'celular' => $newcelular,
            'facebook' => $newfacebook,
            'linkedin' => $newlinkedin,
            'twitter' => $newtwitter,
            'instagram' => $newinstagram
        );

    var_dump($_POST);

    $this->Contato->alterarContato($id, $dados);
    redirect('Agenda');
}
```

Quando dou um `var_dump($_POST)` acontece isso

```php
array(0) { }
```

Comment: vc está chamando a função quando? ajax? via action? Precisa postar mais código aí para te ajudarmos

Comment: estou fazendo por rota, via action estou usando o codeigniter, a minha rota e essa alterando_contato. eu consigo chegar na função de fato, mas nao consigo recuperar os dados do formulario

Comment: precisaria desses codigos, para entender aonde ele está se perdendo

Comment: qual vc precisa? o unico q nao mandei foi a rota que e essa aqui

$route['alterando_contato/(:num)'] ='Agenda/alterarContato/$1';

mas me diz o q mais vc precisa q eu mando

Comment: Me parece que seu problema é o botão alterar, ele é um `<a href=` com o link, tente fazer o seguinte: Coloque a url de post no action do seu formulário e no final do seu form troque o `<a href=` por um `<input type='submit' value='alterar'/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marcos, faça o seguinte, troque sua action pelo href que está no link.
Logo após,

```
<form action='<?php echo base_url('alterando_contato').'/'.$contato; ?>' method="post"> 
    <h4>Alterar contato</h4>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nome">Nome completo</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-md" name="newnome" value="<?php echo $contato['nome']; ?>"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">E-mail</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-md" name="newemail" value="<?php echo $contato['email']; ?>"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="telefone">Telefone</label>
        <input type="tel" class="form-control form-control-md" name="newcelular" value="<?php echo $contato['celular']; ?>"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nome">Redes sociais</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-md" name="newfacebook" value="<?php echo $contato['facebook']; ?>"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-md" name="newlinkedin" value="<?php echo $contato['linkedin']; ?>"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-md" name="newtwitter" value="<?php echo $contato['twitter']; ?>"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-md" name="newinstagram" value="<?php echo $contato['instagram']; ?>"/>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Alterar</button>

</form>
```

Feito isto, estará enviando seus dados via post.

Answer (score 0):

Fala Pessoal, obrigado pela ajuda de todos.

Consegui resolver meu problema utilizando um pouco da solução do Leandro e um pouco do que o Icaro postou.

Eu coloquei esse trecho na minha action.

```
'<?php echo base_url('alterando_contato').'/'.$contato['id']?>'
```

e troquei o button por esse trecho.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" value="Alterar">
```